# AWT and Oracle Secure Global Desktop

Tags: java, linux, ssh, awt, remote-access

I develop a GUI using some AWT libs (Ex: java.awt.color). But when I try run this with SGD, it will be crashed.
I removed those libs and it work fine.

When checking the log, I see:

```
[xcb] Too much data requested from _XRead
[xcb] This is most likely caused by a broken X extension library
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
gnome-settings-daemon: ../../src/xcb_io.c:735: _XRead: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_too_much_data_requested' failed.
```

Who know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

add the config to java property
`-Djava.awt.headless=true`
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html if you just use  AWT color.

Comment: Good. The issue gone. I love you :pacpac